# Create a default kernel header file (C)

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel, header-files

I'm having difficulties understanding how GCC searches for headers contained in `<>` (eg. `<stdio.h>`). I have made a system call header file and I want to make it global. How do I proceed?

I have tried including my header file within `usr/include` and then compiling the new kernel (it didn't include my file though).
I have tried running `gcc -Iheaders mysyscalls.h` in the command line. No errors appears but GCC still complains that it can not find my header file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Comment: Since this is a config/makefile issue, there is no code. I reckon I need to add some sort of rule in the kernel's makefile but i have no clue where to even beging learning the syntax